# Deviations in trend for boiling points of straight chain alkanols

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, boiling-point

I was given a set of data about the boiling points of straight chain alkanols from methanol to dodecan-1-ol and noticed that the trend line seemed to be in the shape of a polynomial 4. I have also noticed a similar pattern in a data set for boiling points of alkanoic acids ranging from methanoic acid to decanoic acid. Can anyone explain why this oscillation occurs?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/160008/continuous-variable-for-graph-of-boiling-point-of-different-chain-lengths

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50047/elevated-boiling-points-in-alkanes-with-even-number-of-carbons